# Equivalent of hdparm -t for home directory?

Tags: server, bash, disk, benchmarks, hdparm

I want to test the read speed on an Ubuntu Server hard drive like one would do with `hdparm -t`, but I need to automatically this on multiple machines where I don't know beforehand what `dev` the main HDD is, so I can't just `hdparm -t /dev/sda`. I would like to be able to run it on the `home` folder or on the hard drive containing it, if there's a way to do that in bash.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `findmnt -T` ex.

```
$ findmnt -T /home
TARGET SOURCE    FSTYPE OPTIONS
/home  /dev/sda6 ext4   rw,relatime,data=ordered
```

or to extract just the block device

```
$ findmnt -no SOURCE -T /home
/dev/sda6
```

To use it with `hdparm`:

```
hdparm -t "$(findmnt -no SOURCE -T /home)"
```